# I'm trying to print the integers from 0 to 100 and identify the prime numbers

Tags: python, function

I've worked a lot on this but I can't figure out the problem. Can you help me?
The code should print numbers from 0 to 100 and print next to the prime numbers "Prime". The first function works but if I try to print the numbers all togheter the "prime" tag gets misplaced.

```
def testPrime(numTest):
if numTest <= 1:
    return False
if numTest == 2:
    return True
for i in range(2, numTest):
    if (numTest % i) == 0:
        return False 
    else:
        return True

def printPrimes (lenght):
    i = 0
    while i <= lenght:
        if testPrime(i):
            print(str(i) + "Prime")
        else:
            print(str(i))
        i += 1

printPrimes(100)
```

Comment: You have issues with indentation. However, even if you correct the apparent logic in your testPrime function, it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

The logic in *testPrime()* is flawed. There are faster techniques but here's a trivial approach that may help:

```
def testPrime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2:
        return True
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Thank you. Too early in the morning. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Since a prime number is defined a number a natural number greater than 1 that is not a product of two smaller natural numbers

I think this is the only lines you need.

```py
def testPrime(n):
  for i in range(2,n):
    if n%i == 0:
      return False
  return True
```